# After applying PCA ,K-means assigns a center that is far from the cluster it self

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

My data contains about 1200 observations and 25 features. I performed dimensionality reduction with PCA, and then used k-means.

It seems I'm getting random centers, as they are far from the cluster itself. Look at the yellow cluster for example, where is its center?

Notice that the clusters didn't move at all when I changed the k value, and the output I'm getting is just wrong. Have a look, this is for k = 3:

[image]

and this is for k = 2, the `kmeans.cluster_centers_` is:

```
array([[-0.10621571, -0.33357351, -0.31757225, -0.41859302, -0.34180062,
        -0.40582209, -0.39882614, -0.41326583, -0.40258176, -0.27391731,
        -0.38387384, -0.373283  ,  0.30265487, -0.16514534, -0.38956931,
        -0.18097048, -0.38672061, -0.38919503, -0.3935108 , -0.26672966,
        -0.3337329 , -0.27723583, -0.29186106, -0.32065177, -0.29334765],
       [ 0.47938423,  1.50551998,  1.43330135,  1.88923921,  1.54265145,
         1.8316001 ,  1.80002522,  1.86519597,  1.81697549,  1.23627317,
         1.73254086,  1.68474116, -1.36597464,  0.74535178,  1.75824629,
         0.8167755 ,  1.74538923,  1.75655704,  1.77603542,  1.20383309,
         1.50623935,  1.25125068,  1.31725887,  1.44720019,  1.3239683 ]])
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

##### Here is the code:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(scores_data)
metadata['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_

# Apply PCA to the data to visualize the clusters in 2D
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(scores_data)

plt.scatter(pca_result[:, 0], pca_result[:, 1], c=metadata['cluster'], s=50)

cluster_centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(cluster_centers[:, 0], cluster_centers[:, 1], c='red', marker='o')

# Add labels to the cluster centers
for i, center in enumerate(cluster_centers):
    plt.annotate(f"Cluster {i}", (center[0], center[1]), 
                 textcoords="offset points", 
                 xytext=(0,10), ha='center', fontsize=20)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (16,11)
plt.show()
```

Comment: But this just uses the first and second columns of the original data `scores_data`, doesn't it? My data has much more columns and I would like to use them all, not only the first two.. @cottontail